# Scaladoc options with Maven

Tags: scala, maven, scaladoc, scala-maven-plugin

I'm looking for help with the `scala-maven-plugin` for Maven. I would like to generate my Scaladoc but I'm having some problems with it.

I actually can create my Scaladoc typing the following command:

```
mvn scala:doc
```

The problem now is that I want to add some options when I generate the Scaladoc, such as `-no-link-warnings`.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have found a way (the code below works), but I don't think that's the way I should be done.

My pom file is:

```xml
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-no-link-warnings</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
   ...
   </plugins>
```

---

**EDIT**

A better approach has been suggested by the user Tunaki on the first reply, you can see the code there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your configuration is entirely correct, although you could write it a bit diffently. Currently (forgetting the part about compiling the sources), you have:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-no-link-warnings</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With such a configuration, you declare that every execution of the `scala-maven-plugin` will have the additional argument `-no-link-warnings`. This is because you are declaring it inside the global configuration element. You can have a configuration that is specific to an execution of the plugin, exactly like what you have for the compiling part:

```xml
<execution>
    <id>Compile</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

This configuration will only be taken into account when the execution `Compile` will be invoked.

---

As such, it would be preferable to change your configuration to be specific to an execution of the plugin, because the argument `-no-link-warnings` is really specific to generating the Scaladoc.

This would be the final plugin declaration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Scaladoc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>doc</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-no-link-warnings</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>Compile</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                    <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, when you package your project with `mvn package` for example, the Scaladoc will be automatically generated with the correct argument.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I've been thinking about this and there is still one thing I can't really achieved . What if I want to execute the command `mvn scala:doc` to generate just the documentation?Again, I have tried several configurations but they doesn't seem to read the arguments.

Comment: @Rors If you are using the latest Maven, you could use `mvn scala:doc@Scaladoc` to execute this specific execution.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could also do something like that with Maven, I still need to learn many things. Perfectly clear again, thank you very much